# Displaying points as ordered pairs

Tags: java, math

**I need an answer to this ASAP.** So I have everything in this working fine I just need to display my x1,y1,x2,y2 as ordered pairs when i run the application. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //class used for user input

public class PointSlope
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
   {

   // declare variables
   double x1;
   double y1;
   double x2;
   double y2;
   double slope;
   double distance;
   Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in); // set up scanner
                                             // to read user inputs

  //store values in variables
  System.out.print ( "Enter x1" );
  x1 = reader.nextDouble();
  System.out.print ( "Enter y1" );
  y1 = reader.nextDouble();
  System.out.print ( "Enter x2" );
  x2 = reader.nextDouble();
  System.out.print ( "Enter y2" );
  y2 = reader.nextDouble();

  //calculate slope
  slope=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);

  //calculate distance
  distance = Math.sqrt ((x1-x2) * (x1-x2) + (y1-y2) * (y1-y2));

  //display result

  System.out.println ( "The distance between the 2 points is," + distance +
                      ",units" );
  System.out.println
                      ( "The slope of 2 points is," + slope +
                      ",units" ) ;

    }// end of class
} // end of class
```

Comment: "_I need an answer to this ASAP._" Okay. And? So what errors do you get? [Or what have you tried](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)?

Comment: you may be in bind but not a good reason to be demanding like this.

Comment: so what is the problem Sysout it as `"("+x1+","+y1+")"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like this?

```
System.out.println 
                  ("("+x1+","+y1+")" );
```

and

```
  System.out.println 
                  ("("+x2+","+y2+")" );
```

to show as (x,y)?

Comment: Okay, sorry for sounding rude in my request. I have fixed the issue and everything is working. Thank you guys so much!